# SAS EG date issue

Tags: date, sas

i want to build a bar chart where the X-axis is month year ( example : NOV 2010)
in my dataset i got a column called MonthYear contains the month year value. 
The problem is when i use the MonthYear column as the X-axis value , in the bar chart X-axis it come out numeric value (example : 14800 ...). I google out and found out that it is the date value in SAS.

i would like to know how can i display date as "NOV 2010" form on X-axis in bar chart.

- i tried to change it into a character value column but it is sort alphabetically.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the format monyy7. on the MonthYear column of the source dataset.

Comment: my current dataset date format is DDMMYY10 , when i link to Chart , the value came out at X-axis is still the numeric value instead of date value. No matter what date format i use the X-axis value is still SAS date value.